# retrieve data sqlite3 into list python

Tags: python, sqlite, cursor, fetchall

I want to retrieve data from sqlite3 table, this is my code, but I only get an empty list. I checked my query on the sqlite3 and it works fine there.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("testee.db")
c = conn.cursor()
myquery = ("SELECT stock FROM testproduct WHERE store=3;")
c.execute(myquery)
templist=list(c.fetchall())
```

But templist is empty.

Comment: are you sure you have that data?  what happens when you run the sql directly?

Answer (score 2):

instead of extracting the execute statement in list, try this:

```
    rows=c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
         print(row)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out the error just now. The database file in that directory was empty. I copied the filled in file to the directory python is running and it works fine.

Comment: LOL... well, thanks anyway for the sample code. it was useful to me